# When an enemy Pharah kills herself with an OoD on will it count towards Zenyatta's eliminations?

Tags: overwatch

When Zenyatta uses his Orb of Discord on an enemy Pharah, and she kills herself using her own rockets, will this count towards Zenyatta's eliminations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this won't count towards Zen's eliminations. Zen has to at least do some damage himself to get credit for the kill. It will count as an offensive assist though.